# numpy int larger than 63 bit gives incorrect calculation

Tags: python, numpy, int, modulo

### Calculating modulo with numpy for large integer (>63 bits) sometimes gives incorrect results.

For example:

```
import numpy

numpy.mod(12345678912345679000, 3)
numpy.mod(12345678912345679001, 3)
numpy.mod(12345678912345679002, 3)
```

all give the result of `1.0`. Note that there is no `8` between the second `7` and `9`.

This could be due to the int being larger than 63 bits.

---

### However, sometimes the correct results are outputted.

For example,

```
numpy.mod(123456789123456789100, 3)
numpy.mod(123456789123456789101, 3)
numpy.mod(123456789123456789102, 3)
```

give the correct results of `1`, `2`, and `0`, respectively. Note these new ints are 3 bits longer than before with the addition of `8` between the second `7` and `9`.

Any idea why numpy.mod would have this behavior and how can I work with large ints (>63 bits) in a consistent manner with numpy?

Thanks in advance!

---

I'm running Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on 64-bit windows with numpy v1.18.1.

Comment: `int64` is the normal `numpy` integer `dtype`

Comment: Try: `12345678912345679000%3`.  Python integers are not limited to 64 bits.

Comment: if that is the reason,try changing `dtype` to `uint64`

Comment: `uint64` doesn't seem to help. Even if it did it would only gain one bit.

Comment: What complicates things is that `np.array(...)` creates `np.int64` numbers, then `np.uint64`, and the `object` dtype as they get bigger.  With object dtype the `mod` uses the Python `%`, which is fine.  There's a small region around 64 bits where the `mod` is producing an erroneous float.  Elsewhere it is producing a valid integer.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! That makes a lot of sense. The reason I want to use numpy is for the faster array operations since I have to take a bunch of mods. But I guess I can do normal python `%` for these troublemakers around 64 bits.

Comment: For single values or a small list, direct use of `%` will be faster than `np.mod` (even in a list comprehension).  If it's already an array `np.mod` should be faster, especially for large arrays.  But if you have to revert to object dtype arrays, the speed drops back to the list comprehension range.

Comment: Got it. I do have large arrays. Will set dtype to 'object' when necessary then.